# with ngx-device-detector, getting error of - Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not generic

Tags: angular, typescript

In my project I have ngx-device-detector of latest version and @angular/core version is 5.0.0 when I try to run my project I am not able to run it and it is showing error like:

> ERROR in node_modules/ngx-device-detector/index.d.ts(3,23): error TS2315: Type 'ModuleWithProviders' is not generic.

here is my `package.json`

```
"@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
"ngx-device-detector": "^1.4.2"
```

Am I mistaking something?

Comment: I know this is pretty old but have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @halfer, I updated my angular version on my local system.. In short, there is version issue. We have to upgrade it..

Comment: That was for @MarksASP I think - I am just the editor of the question.

Comment: Okay.. My bad.. @MarksASP, I updated my angular version of my local system..